# How to check array for new entries and post it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looking for a little help with array. So I have array that looks like that:

```
[1]
["Name"]: "Peter"
["Age"]: "22"

[2]
["Name"]: "John"
["Age"]: "34"

[3]
["Name"]: "Shani"
["Age"]: "26"
...
```

I have a function that scraps data from a table and updates array every 10s, so it might be the case that array will grow bigger or even shrink. What I would like to do is to monitor new entries and post them like...
Hey! Dwight joined us and he is 31!

Can you please point me out the direction where I should look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to look at the new array and compare it with a previous version. Here is a little demo of how you could set it up:

```js
const arr=[{id:122,name:"Peter",age:22,sex:"m"},{id:7,name:"John",age:34,sex:"m"},{id:542,name:"Shany",age:26,sex:"m"},{id:21,name:"Daisy",age:16,sex:"f"}];
const arrnew=[{id:122,name:"Peter",age:22,sex:"m"},{id:73,name:"Daniel",age:34,sex:"m"},{id:21,name:"Daisy",age:16,sex:"f"},{id:14,name:"Florence",age:45,sex:"f"}];

arr.idx={}; // make the old array "searchable"
arr.forEach(c=>arr.idx[c.id]=1);
arrnew.forEach(c=>arr.idx[c.id] || console.log(`Hey, ${c.name} joined us, ${c.sex=="f"?"s":""}he is ${c.age}.`))
```

You could get the array `newarr` from your "scraping" operation (with `fetch()` or another AJAX method). Before getting a new `newarr` array it should be renamed  to `arr`.

Obviously, instead of `console.log()` you would put your own messaging code in there.

**Please note:**
I added the properties `id` and `sex` to the individual person objects. The `id` is *unique* - without it you would not be able to distinguish between two "Peters" of the same age.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the array filter method to compare both arrays with each other and announce the difference, e.g:

```js
const old_array = ["a", "b"];
const new_array = ["a", "c", "e"];

const removals = old_array.filter(v => new_array.indexOf(v) < 0);
const additions = new_array.filter(v => old_array.indexOf(v) < 0);

console.log("Additions:", additions);
console.log("Removals", removals);
```